# How to create a Maven project as jar file with comments included in the jar for each method

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar

**I have Maven project**

*All the java files are located in src/test/java*

**My pom.xml as below**

```
 <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>manual-jar</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>manual</classifier>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    <classpathPrefix>${project.build.finalName}-manual.lib/</classpathPrefix>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When i run the command **mvn clean install -DskipTests**, I have the jar file created in target folder.

but when i use it in other project, Methods under the class files with  **comments/multiline comments** are ***not shown in the jar***. please help here.

This is how i have commented in the method

```
/*
     * Returns an Image object that can then be painted on the screen.
     * The url argument must specify an absolute <a href="#{@link}">{@link "url"}</a>. The name
     * argument is a specifier that is relative to the url argument.
     * <p>
     * This method always returns immediately, whether or not the
     * image exists. When this applet attempts to draw the image on
     * the screen, the data will be loaded. The graphics primitives
     * that draw the image will incrementally paint on the screen.
     *
     * @param  url  an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
     * @param  name the location of the image, relative to the url argument
     * @return      the image at the specified URL
     * @see   String
     */
    public String abc(String name, String url){
        String c =name+url;
        return c ;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "comments included in the jar"? You can use the maven source plugin to create a source artefact.

Comment: It does not make sense to put all Java sources into `src/test/java`. The directory `src/test/java` is only for testing the running build, but if there is nothing in `src/main/java`, there is nothing to test.

Comment: If the given `All the java files are located in src/test/java` is true you have a full misunderstanding of how maven works. As already @JFabianMeier described...move the java files to their appropriate location.

Comment: @J Fabian Meier and @khmarbaise, i have moved everything from src/test/java to src/main/java, when i build this project now, I get package with resources also (which i dont want)

also when i use this jar in other project, methods were not recognised.

Comment: Please make an example project on github or alike to show the real world... that's easier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the maven-source plugin.

POM configuration for source:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-sources</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

POM configuration for javadoc:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-javadocs</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html

Comment: Thanks @xalves, i get below error when i run mvn clean install

MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc: 
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: warning - No source files for package test.java.com.terminaldriver.common.logger

Comment: @Gireesh I believe you can add the property failOnError then. I would expect at least some of the docs to be generated. If not, perhaps more insight on that package is required.  `<configuration><failOnError>false</failOnError></configuration>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the source & javadoc artifacts as part of your build, the process for which is described in the [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html).

This is how IDEs are able to document third-party APIs. Comments are not converted to byte code, so they are stripped from the compiled class by default.