# how can I retain javadoc on class with maven?

Tags: java, maven

How can I retain comments on classes during Maven packaging? I noticed that the classes in the maven-shade-plugin.jar have comments, and it seems quite intriguing to me.

[image]

I tried ChatGPT's suggestion, but it didn't work.

```xml
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/*.class</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: duplicated with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68666577/how-to-create-a-maven-project-as-jar-file-with-comments-included-in-the-jar-for)

Comment: @bob this is for a shaded jar, that isn’t.

Comment: I want comments on class in xxx.jar,not comments on java source in xx-sources.jar.I'm just curious abount how maven achieve this goal.@Bob